# I can not make yii migration

Tags: php, database, yii2

I tried to work with yii basic migrations. yii migrate/create is working, yii migrate - not.

I use command *php yii migrate*. I get the following message:

> Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'could not find driver'
>
> in ../basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php:547

I have found  advice that I need to add some files from advanced yii to my basic. I do not know what should be done exactly.

Comment: And can we see your code or what you've done to solve the problem?

Comment: Try to run: `php requirements.php` at root folder.

Comment: @XiaosongGuo It shows some warnings. I think this important: "PDO MySQL extension: WARNING!!!". I have checked php.ini and removed semi colon near "extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll". No result.

Answer (score 0):

You should install extension to your php of DB, which you are using. In case it is already installed, make sure that it is properly turned on in your php-cli settings.

For example, in case you are using Ubuntu and php5-fpm you can run

`sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`

Comment: I use LAMPP. Should I additionally install mysql?

Comment: I use "php yii migrate".Error - 'yii\db\Exception', error in "../basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php:547". I use this lesson to understand yii, but I always have this error. It is in Russian https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cugnRoZ1ick

Comment: @Dima which DB config are you using? Can you update your question with DB config and php.ini config?

Comment: what exactly should I show?  I have checked php.ini and removed semi colon near "extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll". No result